# C# not recognising variable

Tags: c#, function

I am trying to compare to the p value generated in void aim, I run the `aim()` function within the timer, yet when it comes to `if (score>p)` it does not recognize the `P` variable, how can i make it so the if statement works, where it is comparing against the `P` value generated within the aim function.

```
void aim()
{
    int p;
    p = n.Next(2, 5);
    OppScore.Text = (string.Format("Target Score: {0}", p));
}

Random m = new Random();
Random n = new Random();

public void RunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    target();

    if (lives <= 0)
    {
        left--;
        lives = 2;
        TimesLeft.Text = (string.Format("attempts left: {0}", left));
        TimesLeft.Text = Convert.ToString(left);
    }

    if (left <= 0)
    {
        this.Hide();
        new Game_Over().Show();
        RunTimer.Stop();
    }

    if (counter<1)
    {
        aim();
        counter++;
    }

    if (score > p)
    {
        this.Hide();
        new Winner().Show();
        RunTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: `p` is out of scope. Do a little research on what "scope" means in programming.

Comment: How can I get it in scope

Comment: Can you share full code of yours, looks like you should put 'P' globally than locally.

Comment: [This is a basic concept](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) you must understand to be an effective programmer. I could tell you to put a certain line of code somewhere instead of where it is but I hope you would be interested in learning how and why.

Comment: I would like to learn why, however I'm running on a very very short deadline right now

Comment: Assuming both methods are defined in the same class you can make `p` a field in that class instead of a local variable inside of `aim`.

Comment: FYI you shouldn't need two instances of `Random`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the line:

```
int p;
```

To be the next line under:

```
Random n = new Random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lewis,

as said in the comments by all, you have initialized the 'p' variable locally.

```
RunTimer_Tick(...)
```

is different from `aim(...)` 
so if you want that to work then you have to put the variable 'p' globally so that its value will be retained for the entire program, than just using it as a local variable.

I hope you got what we are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `p` is visible only to the `aim()` method due to scope. It's a very basic construct of programming.

In order to render the variable visible to other methods in the same class you'll have to bring it to **class level scope**

```
private int p;

Random m = new Random();
Random n = new Random();

void aim()
{
    p = n.Next(2, 5);
    OppScore.Text = (string.Format("Target Score: {0}", p));
}



public void RunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    target();

    if (lives <= 0)
    {
        left--;
        lives = 2;
        TimesLeft.Text = (string.Format("attempts left: {0}", left));
        TimesLeft.Text = Convert.ToString(left);
    }

    if (left <= 0)
    {
        this.Hide();
        new Game_Over().Show();
        RunTimer.Stop();
    }

    if (counter < 1)
    {
        aim();
        counter++;
    }

    if (score > p)
    {
        this.Hide();
        new Winner().Show();
        RunTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

In the code above you can see that by declaring the variable outside the method and within the class your variable gets visible to all methods within the class.

```
private int p;
```

Comment: however if i declare it outside of that, it doesn't use the p value from the function

Comment: the initial value of p is 0 as it's an integer. When the function is called the value for `p` will be set. You can yourself initialize the value of `p` to any desired initial value as well.